# Can jquery.ajax post a value from an attribute Name?

Tags: php, jquery

Can jquery.ajax post a value from an attribute Name? If can, I want send image's title `apple` to b.php, then return the data `This is an apple` from b.php to the `div#result`, Thanks.

a.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script language="javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () {      
var params = "value=" + $('#send').attr(title);  
$.ajax({        
     url:'b.php',        
     type:'post',                 
     dataType:'html',            
     data:params,                
     success:data     
     }); 
function data (html) {     
$("#result").html(html);  
} 
}); 
</script> 
<body> 
<div id="result"></div>
<img id="send" src="apple.jpg" title="apple" />
</body>
</html>
```

b.php

```
<?php
echo 'This is an '.$_REQUEST['value'].'.'; 
?>
```

Comment: Put quotes around 'title' in your call to .attr()

Comment: Right, my careless, forget quotes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put quotes around the attribute name, `.attr('title')`,  it should work. Otherwise, `title` will be treated as variable, and, as it is not defined, it will have the value `undefined`.

But better is to pass an object to `data` and let jQuery take care of proper encoding:

```
$.ajax({        
    url:'b.php',        
    type:'post',                 
    dataType:'text', // actually, you are not outputting HTML
    data: {value: $('#send').attr('title')},                
    success:data     
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't set the 'values' parameter in the same way you set a normal variable in this application.  Instead you could create an object with a member called "value" and set that equal to your image title.

```
var params = new Object();
params.value = $('#send').attr('title');
```

Or you could create params as a literal like:

```
var params = {value: $('#send').attr('title')};
```